# Spring boot framework fails to find MongoRepository if its from different package other than root package

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mongo

I am building an application using Spring boot framework. Below are my package structure.

- com.example.dal -> contains MongoRepositories
- com.example.app -> web
  application and contains main method to spring
  application

The spring framework not able to find repositories if they are in 'com.example.dal' package. But works as expected if they are in 'com.example.app'. I tried different options like below

```
@ComponentScan("com.example.dal") 

@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackages = {"com.example.dal"})
```

But none of them solves the issue.
Did any one face the same issue? 
Or is it an issue with Spring framework ?

Comment: Can you try with `@EntityScan` to see if that fixes your problem?

Comment: Are you sure that the class that you have annotated is considered as a Spring component?